\citep Not Formatting References with "et al." Using cas-model2-names.bst File
I am using the \citep command in my LaTeX document to cite references, and I expect it to format the references using "et al." when there are multiple authors, as shown in examples I've seen. However, when I compile my document, the full list of authors is displayed instead of the "et al." abbreviation for the 2nd but not the 1st example.
Moreover, I used the suggestion given in the Tex to its backwards: How to change citation call-outs from authoryear-style to numeric-style?
Here is the setup I’m using:

I downloaded the cas-model2-names.bst file from this GitHub link.
My bibliography file is correctly referenced in the LaTeX document.
I am using the natbib package for citations, and the document class is
compatible with this bibliography style.

Here is a minimal example of my LaTeX code:
%\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-sc}
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

% \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample1}
\section{Sample2}
\section{Sample3}

\section{Bibliography styles}

This is a citation example 1: \citep{menezes2017towards} found that...

This is a citation example 2 \citep{menezes2017towards}] obtained a different result ...

%% Loading bibliography style file
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{cas-refs}

\end{document}


Expected Output:
This is a citation example 1: (Menezes et al. 2017) found that...

Actual Output:
This is a citation example 1: Menezes, Samara, Galway, Sant’Anna, Verikas, Alonso-Fernandez, Wang and Bond (2017) found that...

The example given in the Elsevier Template shows as: .
Whereas the other option \citet gives a similar result.
Output:

cas-ref.bib file
  title={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pellentesque ex id ligula efficitur},
  author={Menezes, Maria Luiza Recena and Samara, Anas and Galway, Leo and Sant’Anna, Anita and Verikas, Antanas and Alonso-Fernandez, Fernando and Wang, Hui and Bond, Raymond},
  journal={Lorem ipsum dolor},
  volume={21},
  pages={1003--1013},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{luque2019impact,
  title={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pellentesque ex id ligula efficitur},
  author={Luque, Amalia and Carrasco, Alejandro and Mart{\'\i}n, Alejandro and de Las Heras, Ana},
  journal={Lorem ipsum},
  volume={91},
  pages={216--231},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

Update
For references cited a second time, the output is as expected. In the image below, Examples 1 and 3 are in an incorrect format, while Examples 2 and 4 are in the expected format.
\section{Bibliography styles}

This is a citation example 1: \citep{menezes2017towards} found that...
This is a citation example 2: \citep{menezes2017towards} obtained a different result ...

This is a citation example 3: \citep{luque2019impact} obtained a different result ...

This is a citation example 4: \citep{luque2019impact} obtained an expected result ...

Output:


Does the cas-sc document class load natbib automatically? If so, with which options?

In the cas-sc document there is nothing about natbib, I'm using the Elsevire single column Template from https://www.elsevier.com/researcher/author/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions

Please edit your query and post the code (from the .bib) file of one or two entries that are giving you trouble (in the sense that the citation call-out isn't truncated to "firstauthor et al.").

In an update, you mention that "For references cited a second time, the output is as expected". This strongly suggests that your code -- or the document class or one of the packages you employ -- is loading the natbib package with the option longnamesfirst. Get rid of this option if you want truncated citation call-outs right away.

@Mico, That works. Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue (caused by the document class loading natbib with the option longnamesfirst) was resolved in a comment.
